# In PowerBI Desktop how can we display the filters selected in the Report

Tags: powerbi

In my PowerBI report, I have a hierarchy slicer and a graph showing data as per the data selected in the hierarchy slicer. I need a text box showing the filters/data selected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite a text box, but possibly using tables or multi-row cards will work for you?

[image]

[image]

You could use formatting to hide undesired labels:

[image]

And if you need to show some accompanying text you could align a regular text box:

[image]

**Edit**

Taking into account multiple items being selected,

Use this measure for the label:

```
label = IF(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Column1])=
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Column1]),ALL(Table1)),
    "All",
    IF(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Column1])=1,
        FIRSTNONBLANK(Table1[Column1],1),
        "Multiple"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to show "All" if none or any of slicer values are selected?